# Create Floating Marker Google Maps iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-markers

is there any idea how to create floating marker that could pick its location but keep in its center view, plus its map can be scrolled? 
I found the javascript version

```js
function initialize() {
  var crosshairShape = {
    coords: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    type: 'rect'
  };
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.62279178711505, -5.895538330078125);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    }
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
  });
  document.getElementById('coordinates').innerHTML = "<b>center coordinates</b>: " + map.getCenter().toUrlValue(6)
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('coordinates').innerHTML = "<b>center coordinates</b>: " + map.getCenter().toUrlValue(6);
  });
  marker.bindTo('position', map, 'center');
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div id="coordinates"></div>
```

There is an app that already implemented this, but I really don't have a clue how to do that. Here is the image

[image: Center marker]

My point is, every user scrolled the map, its marker keep on center view then we could get its coordinate (GMSPlace or any coordinate).

Any help or clue would be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have added an image in the center of MapView and would take its coordinate as user stop scrolling.

To Create ImageView:

```
UIImageView *pin = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame(0,0,10,10)];
pin.center = self.view.center;
pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin"];
[self.view addSubview:pin];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:pin];
```

To get Coordinate:

```
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
{
CGPoint point = pin.center;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coor = [mapView.projection coordinateForPoint:point];
CGFloat longitude = coor.longitude;
CGFloat latitude = coor.latitude;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I wont write it all out but:

dont use a marker for this at all ;) just use a plain UIView added as a subview of the map .. centered.

and the center coordinate is just the center coordinate of the visible region

Comment: Thank you so much, @Daij-Djan!

Answer (score 2):

Below code should help you.

```
// Call this function from -viewdidload with valid GMSMapView input.
- (UIImageView *)addMarkerOnMapViewCenter:(GMSMapView *)mapView
{
    UIView *vwMapParentView = mapView.superview;
    UIImageView *vwMarker = [UIImageView new];
    [vwMarker setFrame:(CGRect){0,0,20,40}];
    // Customize the Background color as per your need.
    [vwMarker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    // Drop an icon named markerIcon.png in your project bundle
    [vwMarker setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"markerIcon.png"]];
    [vwMarker setCenter:(CGPoint){vwMapParentView.center.x,(vwMapParentView.center.y - vwMarker.frame.size.height)}]; // if needed subtract navigation bar height as well as per the requirement.
    [vwMapParentView addSubview:vwMarker];
    [vwMapParentView bringSubviewToFront:vwMarker];
    return vwMarker;
}
// And then,Implement this GMSMapView's delegate method.
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D target = position.target;
    NSLog(@"%f : %f",target.latitude,target.longitude);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks, Naresh.

Answer (score 1):

As [Daij-Djan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420303/daij-djan) said, don't add as marker. Just use a plain UIView/UIImageView add as a subview of the map centred. Then implement this code Google maps **didChangeCameraPosition** or **idleAtCameraPosition** delegate:

```
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
{
    CGPoint point = mapView.center;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coor = [mapView.projection coordinateForPoint:point];
}
```